# Please explain the meaning given code snippet in react js

Tags: javascript

Below is the code used in server.js file in a react js application. But I am not able to understand the syntax of this statement. Here after require('webpack-dev-middleware') there is no `.` used and suddenly another bracket started with some arguments. Can someone please explain how is it working?

```
app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
noInfo: true,
publicPath: config.output.publicPath
}));
```

Comment: I would recommend adding a "react" tag as well.

Comment: @Taurus, the post had one, but I removed it. OP's app might be React, but the question is per se irrelevant to React. This is a general JS question.

Comment: @Taurus I wouldn't, this is not about ReactJS

Comment: @Chris Ahh excuse me, never worked with React and i just assumed that it had something to do with React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require('webpack-dev-middleware')` is returning a function. This is just a shortened version of this

```
const webpackMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
const webpackCompiler = webpackMiddleware(compiler, {
    noInfo: true,
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath
});
app.use(webpackCompiler);
```

Answer (score 1):

`require('webpack-dev-middleware')` returns a function.

The second set of brackets contain arguments to be passed to this returned function.

Answer (score 0):

Simply extract parts of this expression as separate variables

```
const createWebpackMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware')
const options = {
  noInfo: true,
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath
}
const webpackMiddleware = createWebpackMiddleware(compiler, options)

app.use(webpackMiddleware );
```